# How can I alter response body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, response

This is the scenario where I am storing several attributes into the database. Now, while I fetch the response I don't want the exact attribute name what's already stored in Db. For eg, below is my code. Here, I have stored fields as 'ca_xyz'.Now while fetching the response I want only only 'xyz' as fieldname. Can anyone help me?

```
const addAddress = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        var custid = req.params.id;
         const data = {
             ca_email: req.body.email,
             ca_mobile: req.body.mobile,
             ca_address1: req.body.address1,
             ca_address2: req.body.address2,
             ca_zone_id: req.body.zone_d,
             ca_city: req.body.city,
             ca_local: req.body.local,
             ca_pincode: req.body.pincode,
         }
         let results = await Address.create({data});
         res.send({
            status:'success',
            message:`Successfully added address `
         })
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        res.send({
            status:'failed',
            message:"An error occurred"
        })

    }
}
```

Actually, this is what is happening. It should loop inside dataValues but here it is getting 'customer_group' object.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The type-safe way would be to write this by hand, and the fast way would be the following, by looping through the Object's entries and deleting the prefix of each key.

```js
const data = {
  ca_email: "req.body.email",
  ca_mobile: "req.body.mobile",
  ca_address1: "req.body.address1",
  ca_address2: "req.body.address2",
  ca_zone_id: "req.body.zone_d",
  ca_city: "req.body.city",
  ca_local: "req.body.local",
  ca_pincode: "req.body.pincode",
}

let newData = {};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  newData[key.substr("ca_".length)] = value;
}

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Hii, i tried this but I am not getting the desired response

Comment: Excuse me? This is exactly the logic you asked for. What's wrong?

Comment: Even i felt this logic is correct but Its not looping inside key value pair.. I am adding a snapshot to make it clear.

Comment: That's exactly what you asked for, the output is your object with different keys. You can then save it. I can't do anything else unless you explain more clearly what you're really asking for.

Comment: Now, can you tell? I have added a snapchot

Comment: My best advice would be to store the data differently and store the prefix separately. Sorry, can't help more.